# getInputStream freezes and never finishes

Tags: java

Im reading a simple text file from my website using  HttpURLConnection, and when it calls getInputStream it freezes and never finishes, the getResponseCode returns 200. It was working at first every time then it stopped working.

I have search for a solution all over the internet and none work. I think it maybe ddos protection on the web server, or something on there end blocking it.

```
public static String getLatestInfo(String urlString){
URL url = null;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
/*InputStream inputStream = null;
InputStreamReader isr = null;
BufferedReader in = null;*/
try {
    url = new URL(urlString);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds connectTimeout
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds socketTimeout
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

    connection.connect(); 

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream())
            {
                try(InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")) {
                    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr))
                    {
                        String line;
                        String config = "";
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            config = config + line + "\n";
                        }
                        return config;
                    }
                }
            }
        /*inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        String config = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            config = config + line + "\n";
        }
        return config;*/
    }

}
catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
{
    System.out.println("Timeout: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
    try {
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
finally {
    if (connection != null) connection.disconnect();
    /*try {
        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (in != null) in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (isr != null) isr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}
return null;}
```

I started simple and have added all the suggestion that should've fix it.. it gets response code 200 and then freezes on connection.getInputStream()

Comment: How often have you been running this program?  I’m thinking the site may have decided you were connecting too many times in too short a time period.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Don't specify `Content-Type` in a GET request. GET requests don't have content, so there is nothing to specify the type of.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Remember to close your streams. Highly recommend using try-with-resources for that!!!

Comment: Remove `setDoOutput(true)`, since you're not actually doing any output (as you shouldn't for a GET request).

Comment: I've been using it for about a month, i've tried switch host and get the same thing.

Comment: By setting `doOutput` to true you are actually sending a POST here.

Comment: So I started a new project with just the code above and it works fine, is it possible for streams to get crossed?

Comment: @user207421: `setDoOutput(true)` by itself doesn't change to POST, only if you also `getOutputStream()`. Although `setDoOutput(true)` _without_ any output is silly and useless.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple things wrong in my code:

1. Some streams for file reading wasn't closed.
2. I was using `FileInputStream/FileOutputStream` and it was making it freeze. [This](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful) explains it. Even though it shows a work around, but it still would make it freeze.
3. The main problem i was using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable ()...` and it was freeze and random points.

Fixing all the above factors and it solved my problem.